# Extract data from a search field on a website

Tags: html, sql, database

I am looking at a website with a search field. You can search this form for a product and it shows you all products that match the description. Is it possible to extract the date from this database to get a complete list of all the products that are in the database? There are a lot and otherwise I would have to copy everything by hand.

The search form:

```
<form name="search" action="https://www.(site).nl/zoeken/" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input id='catalogueLanguage' type='hidden' value='NL'>
<input
type="search"
name="term"
id="searchTerm"
class="form-control"
placeholder="Zoeken&hellip;"
value=""
autocomplete="off">
<label for='searchTerm' class="sr-only">Zoeken</label>
<span class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-search" type="submit" aria-label='search-submit'>
<svg class="icon icon-search-btn mx-auto" aria-hidden="true">
<use class="header-search" xlink:href="#shape-search-new"></use>
</svg>
</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. But can we have more info? Like the database, the structure of the data, etc?

Comment: As I do not own the website, I unfortunately do not. The code above is all I can extract at the moment

Comment: It seems to be JSON on the webpage